# How to set a shortcut to open terminal / run shell command in Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any setting we could use to set a shortcut to open a Terminal window at the project's directory?
Or even better, run command like `pod install` or `fastlane lane` with a shortcut in Xcode12?

Comment: "Is there any setting we could use to set a shortcut to open a Terminal window at the project's directory?" Yes. There are many ways to do this. Which you use depends on your specific needs. Searching on "mac open terminal in current folder" gives some excellent suggestions.

Comment: "Or even better, run command like pod install or fastlane lane with a shortcut in Xcode12?" You really wouldn't want to say pod install with Xcode open. Really it's probably better to take things one step at a time.

Comment: @matt but it's really useful when you are developing on different branches and it happens that different branches have different pod dependencies, which makes it necessary to run `pod install` every time you switch the branch. In this case, it would very efficient to do that with a shortcut.

Comment: Yes, in that case you'd want to keep a Terminal window open on your project folder at all times.